Any system for determining if a model is applicable to a problem?
Is there any formal system for determining whether a model is applicable or corresponding to a problem? Take the following example:
Problem:
Peter's age is a third of his father's age, but in 10 years his father will only be two times as old as Peter will be. What is Peter's age today?
Solution:
Let x be Peter's age. Let y be the father's age.
y = 3x
y + 10 = 2(x + 10) = 2x + 20
=> 3x + 10 = 2x + 20
=> x = 10
Most of us understand intuitively that this solution works for the problem. But besides intuition is there a system to verify it? Another way to phrase the question is "Is there a system for translating natural language problems to problems in math notation?"

Hmm... this question is a bit of a head-scratcher. It does seem like quite a broad question/opinion-based/not focused enough to me, as it could be answered in a variety of totally different ways.

Natural language is so ambiguous there can't possibly be a guaranteed way to translate it to mathematical notation.
